# Set textcolor of fnmark in Footer

Tags: color, footnotes

I'm modifying `@makefnmark` in the body but keeping it the same in the footer using this code:

```
\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{%
  % ...
}

\let\@latex@makefnmark\@makefnmark
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{\@makefnmark}{\@latex@makefnmark}{}{\FAILED}
% ...

\renewcommand*\@makefnmark{%
  % ...
}
\makeatother
```

How can I change the text color of fnmark in the footer?

When I try with `\textcolor{red}{...}` I'm getting `Undefined control sequence`.

Comment: Why not just `\color{red}` inside  a group?

Comment: I think I'm using the wrong syntax or I'm putting it in the wrong place... Forgive me, I've only been using Latex a few days (so I have tried with `\color` and had the same errors. I'm not sure *how* to use it correctly here).

Comment: @jcuenod Please post a full example. It should contain the *minimum necessary* to show the problem and *compile as is,* so that one can see the problem precisely and can quickly test things after a copy/paste (this is called a [minimal working example, MWE for short](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). I know where the code comes from, but it's a pain to find the post in my history and other people may not know—actually, most won't care to look for it (too many posts, no time to waste with incomplete questions...).

Comment: @jcuenod Of course, when the problem is a compilation error, a MWE is allowed not to compile, but then it should fail to compile *for the reason the question is about,* not from other unrelated errors.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see:

```
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{\@makefnmark}{{\color{red}\@latex@makefnmark}}{}{\FAILED}
```

Why the double curly braces helps, I do not know but here we are...

Comment: That's more or less what I was thinking of.